# trying to call javascript functions in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I'm a bit confused about what I'm doing wrong.

so, I have functions defined in an external .js file like so...

```
var game = (function () {

    function start_game() {
    ...
    }

    function step() {
    ...
    }

...
}
```

Now I want my html page to call these functions; first start_game() once, and then step repeatedly every second or so.

I have tried following the code for doing this in HTML in several posts on this subject but in every case my code is never actually executed... What do I do?

Comment: You can't, you just wrapped those functions in an IIFE, so they are not available, the question is why the heck you would do such a thing?

Comment: It seems `start_game` and `step` are **local** to the IIFE, so they can't be called from the outside.

Comment: to protect the vaiables within the function but with names like that i dont know why you would want to as theyre pretty obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your wrapping all your named functions in an anonymous function like that. (Prob trying something like an IIF) However since your a beginner, take a step and start with something a little more basic.

```
<input type="button" onclick="start_game()" value="click to begin" />
<script>
function start_game() {
...
}
</script>
```

As for having something call a function repeatedly every x seconds. Have a look at something like setTimeout. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: [Please don't link to w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) They're not an authority and often have misinformation. Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) instead

Comment: Your right w3schools are not an authority however for something as basic as setTimeout I considered the Mozilla page but it's a little too much info for a beginner.

Comment: As stated on the w3fools link: For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on.